# AngularJS requests duplicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use AngularJS for my application to send multiple requests to the server. Here is an example of my code

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="AccessCtrl">
```

**Javascript**

```
mainApp.factory('authService', function ($rootScope, $http) {
    return {
        access: function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: some_url,
                data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
            }).success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $rootScope.access_token = response.access_token;
            });
        }
    }
});

controllersApp.controller('AccessCtrl', ['FactoryModule', function (FactoryModule) {
    var testServices = FactoryModule('services');
    testServices.authService.access();
}]);
```

And here is my console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jy2c.png)

I have 2 requests from index and from angular initiators. How to fix this? I want 1 request to get access token.

Comment: The request is to another domain ? If so, it might be a preflight request.

Comment: Code shown is not making 2 requests. Need more details. As mentioned is one of them an OPTIONS request? if so the browser itself does that

Comment: Code making 1 request, but angular is initiator of first request and index initiate duplicate of this request. See attachment image

Comment: Angular execute 1 request, but then index duplicate this request. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/8jy2c.png

Comment: That isn't enough information in that image. Is one of them an OPTIONS request and the other a POST?

Comment: $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://comcomcom:9988/uaa/oauth/token',
                data: 'grant_type=client_credentials',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization': 'Basic SVRXRV9XsfhshhsrhshsW50'
                }
            })

Comment: full code of request

Comment: if that is a different domain or port than page is on...then you will always see a preflight OPTIONS request as part of CORS specification. In network of browser dev tools you can see the request types that aren't shown in your image

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand duplicating)